# Upgrading a binary search algorithm to something more sophisticated

Tags: algorithm, search, optimization, numeric, non-linear

I solved an analytically unsolvable problem with numerical methods. I am searching for X, based on a desired Y value. f(x)=y is possible, x=f^-1(y) is not.

Currently the algorithm does a binary search. It starts at X=50%, calculates Y, returns Y_err=Y-Y_demand. It keeps stepping by intervals of 5% in the direction of shrinking Y_err, until Y_err changes sign, then it reduces the step, and steps in the opposite direction. This works, but it's embarassingly slow & inefficient.

Below, an example chart of x=f^-1(y). I chose one with high coefficients for the nonlinear part.

[Example chart of x=f^-1(y)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2XS4.png)

It varies depending on coefficients, but always has this pseudoparabolic shape. It's of course nonlinear and even 9th order polynomial approximations don't offer satisfactory precision.

For simplicity's sake let's say the inflecton point is at X=50%, and am looking only for solutions where X>50%.

How should I proceed? I'm looking to optimise as much as possible. What are some good algorithms? Thanks.

---

EDIT: Thank you for pointing out that this is not in fact a binary search. I've updated the code and now have much better results by comparison.

I'm not sure if Newton's method applies here, or at least I don't know how to apply it. One-way trial and error is all I can do. When I have some more time I will try to learn and implement regula falsi.

Comment: The algorithm you describe is not binary search. Actually using bisection would already be faster. But also have a look at Newton's method and Regula falsi.

Comment: This sounds more like gradient descent and less like binary search